# Twitter with 1 hashtag in wp7 (read only integration)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, twitter

**Found myself a solution**: Found an own solution. If you want 2 know, contact me.

Don't know to integrate twitter in windows phone app.

What do I have or need:

1. A Hashtag ("zesdaagsegent"), so who tweets to this hashtags, this will be shown in de windows phone app.
2. Only for read, you will not reply in de windows phone app, etc. just read.
3. I need user name of the tweeter, image avatar of the tweeter and his message of course.

This is my try code:

```
WebClient twitter = new WebClient();
            twitter.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(twitter_DownloadStringCompleted);
            twitter.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://search.twitter.com/search.xml?q=23zesdaagsegent"));

public void twitter_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
                return;

            XElement xmlTweets = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

            lstTwitter.ItemsSource = from tweet in xmlTweets.Descendants("status")
                                     select new Tweet
                                     {
                                         ImageSource = tweet.Element("user").Element("profile_image_url").Value,
                                         Message = tweet.Element("text").Value,
                                         UserName = tweet.Element("user").Element("screen_name").Value
                                     };

        }
```

EDIT: I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void FireHashSearch()
        {
            //string searchQuery = string.Format(TWITTER_URL, "%23zesdaagsegent", _MaxSearchResultsCount);
            Uri searchQueryUri = new Uri(URI, UriKind.Absolute);
            searchTwitter = new WebClient();

            searchTwitter.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(searchTwitter_DownloadStringCompleted);
            searchTwitter.DownloadStringAsync(searchQueryUri);
        }

        public void searchTwitter_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {


            // Grab response.
            string results = e.Result;
            JObject o = JObject.Parse(results);
           // String naam = o.GetValue("text").ToString();



            JToken token = o["results"];
            JArray array =(JArray)(o["results"]);



            for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
            {
                lstTwitter.ItemsSource = ItemsTwitter;
                JToken test = JObject.Parse(array[i].ToString());

                // for(int i = 0; i<token.
                // DataBind.
                this.ItemsTwitter.Add(new Tweet()
                {

                    Avatar = "",

                    Msg = (string)test.SelectToken("text"),
                    User = (string)test.SelectToken("from_user")
                });

            }


        }
```